# Create views programmatically in a RecyclerView.ViewHolder and passing arguments to it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can I create views programmatically in a `ViewHolder` instead of binding them from XML in the classic way as in all examples?
Also, my views need an image filepath in order to be created, how do I pass that to the `ViewHolder`

```
protected static class ImagePreviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public LinearLayout page;

    public ImagePreviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        page = createPage(filePath); // How do I pass the filepath?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did u try create
   View itemView
via code?

for ex.:

```
ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-1));
ll.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000);

tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
tv.setText("sample text goes here");
tv.setBackgroundColor(0x5500ff00);
ll.addView(tv);
```

and

```
ImagePreviewViewHolder holder = new ImagePreviewViewHolder(ll);
```

Comment: So I pass the item to the constructor of the `ViewHolder`?

Comment: Yes, you can write another constructor with `page` as parameter.
Concerning the creation of Views, I think it is better to use `onBindViewHolder` method